# Formatting a csv file to correct format

Tags: ruby, csv

I have downloaded a csv file using HTTParty and saved the file locally so I can inspect it at a later date, however it seems as if the data is not formatted correctly

```
[["Team Name", "User Name", "Dataset Name", "No of Searches", "Credits Remaining"], ["", "",
"DRI", "129", "99085"], ["", "", "Property Register Search (G)", "124", "99414"], ["", "",
"Landline Verification", "1", "99783"], ["", "",
"Equifax (G)", "372", "97798"], ["", "", "Director Register", "135", "98499"], ["", "",
"Mobile Verification", "2", "99845"], ["", "",
"BT OSIS", "428", "91588"], ["", "", 
"Experian (G)", "97", "99913"], ["", "", "Standard (G)",
"873", "82151"], ["", "", "CCJ", "120", "98367"]]
```

So that I can use the `CSV` class provided by ruby i need the data to be in the following format don't I ?

```
Team Name, User Name, Dataset Name, No of Searches, Credits Remaining
"", "", DRI, 129, 99085
"", "", Property Register Search (G), 124, 99414]
"", "", Landline Verification, 1, 99783 
"", "", Equifax (G), 372, 97798
"", "", Director Register, 135, 98499
"", "", Mobile Verification, 2, 99845 
"", "", BT OSIS, 428, 91588]
"", "", Experian (G), 97, 99913
"", "", Standard (G), 873, 82151
"", "", CCJ, 120, 98367
```

What i am looking to achieve is to get to a point where i can hash this out so i could access `Credits Remaining` for the `Dataset Name` `Standard`

Hope that makes sense

Thanks

UPDATE

Thanks to @mudasobwa for your answer, i now have my csv file contents in an array of hashes (I think :) )

```
{"TeamName"=>[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
 "UserName"=>[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
 "DatasetName"=> ["DRI", "PropertyRegisterSearch(G)", "LandlineVerification","Equifax(G)", "DirectorRegister", "MobileVerification", "BTOSIS", "Experian(G)", "Standard(G)","CCJ"],
 "NoofSearches"=>["129", "124", "1", "372", "135", "2", "428", "97", "873", "120"],
 "CreditsRemaining"=>["99085", "99414", "99783", "97798", "98499", "99845", "91588", "99913", "82151", "98367"]
}
```

How would i get the `NoofSearches` that `DatasetName` `DRI` corresponds to, so I would expect to get `129` returned

Comment: I am not sure what ruby requires, but you can easily convert the first to the second. Write a quick program remove all the '[' brackets and replace '],' with line breaks.

Comment: Is that first code sample the CSV you downloaded or something you generated using Ruby?

Comment: So the data seems consistent to me, Reformatting your array shows this:

Comment: So the first example is what is downloaded, the second example is me manually editing the file to show what the data should look like, am i to assume a `gsub` would be beneficial here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example should turn your csv into a array of hashes with the data accessible by former colum names.

```
data = []

CSV.foreach('test.csv', headers: true) { |row| data << row.to_hash }

data.inspect

=> [{:col1=>'value1', :col2=>'value2', :col3=> 'value3'}, 
    {:col1=>'value4', :col2=>"value5", :col3=>'value6'}]
```

Contents of `data.csv` looked like this:

```
col1,col2,col3
value1,value2,value3
value4,value5,value6
```

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_hash' for #<Array:0x00000007faa8a0>`

Comment: How does the content of your csv look? Tried it with:

    col1,col2,col3
    value1,value2,value3
    value4,value5,value6

Comment: i get the same undefined method

Comment: My latest edition fixes and simplifies it even more. Actually a pretty straight forward task.

Comment: Of course it returns `nil`! You have to inspect `data`because thats the array where the row hashes are pushed to. Added `data.inspect`to the example to make it clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95463/discussion-between-richlewis-and-oliver-zeyen).

Comment: thanks for your help, gone through it a few times now and makes sense, nice and easy to search on keys aswell `data.find { |h| h['DatasetName'] == dataset }['CreditsRemaining'].to_i` for example

Answer (score 1):

```
▶ csv = [["Team Name", "User Name", "Dataset Name", "No of Searches", "Credits Remaining"], ["", "",
▷   "DRI", "129", "99085"], ["", "", "Property Register Search (G)", "124", "99414"], ["", "",  
▷   "Landline Verification", "1", "99783"], ["", "",  
▷   "Equifax (G)", "372", "97798"], ["", "", "Director Register", "135", "98499"], ["", "",  
▷   "Mobile Verification", "2", "99845"], ["", "",  
▷   "BT OSIS", "428", "91588"], ["", "",   
▷   "Experian (G)", "97", "99913"], ["", "", "Standard (G)",  
▷ "873", "82151"], ["", "", "CCJ", "120", "98367"]]
```

Then the following will give you what you want:

```
▶ csv.transpose.map { |e| [e.shift, e] }.to_h
```

or:

```
▶ csv.transpose.group_by(&:shift).map { |k, v| [k, v.first] }.to_h
```

To access the `NoofSearches` that `DatasetName` `DRI` corresponds to:

```
▶ hash = csv.transpose.map { |e| [e.shift, e] }.to_h
# ⇓ lookup array of noofs
#                        ⇓ by index of 'DRI' in 'Dataset Name' 
▶ hash['No of Searches'][hash['Dataset Name'].index('DRI')]
```

Comment: ok Ive got to a state where a hash is created (need to understand what transpose is doing, will look into that) but how do i access say the `No of Searches` assigned to the `DatasetName` "Standard"

Comment: I have updated my question, would you be able to take a look please, thanks for your help by the way, it's appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using Array#zip.

Apparently, the file that you downloaded is not in CSV format. But, it seems like the string that you have in the file can be directly evaluated into a Ruby Array even though it's hacky.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

file = File.open("test.data", "r")
#NOTE: eval is evil!
csv_arrs = eval(file.read.gsub("\n", "")) 
file.close

headers = csv_arrs.shift
query = {
  :select => "No of Searches",
  :key => "Dataset Name",
  :value => "DRI"
}

r = csv_arrs.find {|a| Hash[ headers.zip(a) ][ query[:key] ] == query[:value]}
puts r[headers.index(query[:select])]
```